# Getting section names

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm trying to get section names of a fetched result.

```
NSArray *testArray = [self.fetchedResultsController sections];
for (NSString *string in testArray){
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

Like this, I'm getting the memory locations for the pointers. How would I be able to print out the actual section names?

Answer (score 2):

The items in `sections` are not `NSString`s, they are objects conforming to the [`NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo) protocol. The protocol defines a `name` property, so you need to do this:

```
NSArray *testArray = [self.fetchedResultsController sections];
for (id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> ri in testArray){
    NSLog(@"%@", ri.name);
}
```